# About a property of uniform integrability

Tags: probability-theory

In my textbook, there is this definion

> **(Uniform integrability)** Let $H$ be a family of integrable functions in $(\Omega, F,P)$. $H$ is called uniformly integrable if
>   $$\sup\limits_{X \in H} \int_{[|X| > c]} |X| dP \to 0 \text{ when } c \to \infty $$

Using this definition, I have to prove that if $|X| \le Y$, for all $X \in H$ and $Y$ be integrable then $H$ is uniformly integrable.

I attempted to make this evaluation:
$$\int_{[|X| > c]} |X| dP \le  \int_{[|X| > c]} Y dP$$
But then, I'm not sure how to use the assumption that $Y$ be integrable. Is there anything that relates between $A$ and $P(A)$ when you evaluate the Lebeesgue integral on $A$, compared to expectation (the integral on $\Omega$)?

Please give me an insight to the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe that $\{|X| >c\} \subset \{Y>c\}$. Hence $\int_{(|X| >c)} Y dP \leq \int_{(Y >c)} Y dP$. This last integral tends to $0$ as $c \to \infty$ by DCT.

Comment: By "DCT", do you mean the dominated convergence theorem, sir?

Comment: Yes, DCT is dominated convergence theorem.